# In IOT , vehicle parking system designing which data model best suited for millions numbers of concurrent users

Tags: data-structures, iot

I am trying to designing a IOT based  parking slot booking management system.
Here is requirement:

```
 1. Get all available slots for a given location and time period
 2. Dynamic pricing for parking slots as per traffic like more traffic 
       more charges.
 3. Suggestion for available booking slots at near location , in case no    slots available at requested location.
 4. During post analytics  used data model able to give results like 
          a. Most used parking slots
          b. Peak traffic hours
          c. optimize unused traffic slots
 5. In every booking slot there is difference of 30 min. no idea how to optimize this.
 6. How to detect booking slot overlapping and then suggest available booking slot option.
```

I am planning to  design this system with Tree based data model but thing that blocking me is that in case number of concurrent user going to millions then we need to traverse lot's of tree node to get available time slots.  Any better approach to build such system.

Comment: You situation is maybe a little to broad to be a question on here. Is the limit due to hardware you've tested so far or some other issue?

Comment: @PaulAndrew right now we are in designing phase.We have finalized technologies SPRING, REST Web Services, Mongo DB but Data Model part still left.It would be great if you can share some of your thoughts/lead over that .

Comment: Nand, it may not add a thing to your problem, but [this](http://www.internetsociety.org/doc/iot-overview) overview is one of the best I found so far on IoT (I am about to start a job in the field, so I have been doing some research). I am sharing this document specially for the section that touches some of the possibilities for communication models - Device-To-Device, Device-To-Cloud, Device-To-Gateway and Back-End-Data-Sharing models. Perhaps these modelling analysis adds a bit to your analysis and design.

Comment: @Veverke thank you vererke for your input.I will go through doc and will share our experiences to give best design to word.